# track command not found on switch Catalyst 2960-X Series

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

I have a problem with the command "track". I have done this command multiple times on other router and I believe my command is correct. However when I wanted to do this on a switch it shows "Invalid input" and Unrecognized command"

How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? On the 2960, `show ip device tracking` might be what you're after.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: Will take note on that. Thanks for informing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Catalyst 2960 is not that advanced in terms of Layer-3 functionalities and doesn't have ability to create track objects. Maybe if you want to track link state for ether-channel, you could use `link state` option ([link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg_2960/swethchl.html#wp1376466))

Comment: The answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks